# At what stage of computer science PhD should you start looking for post-doc?

Tags: phd, funding, postdocs

I am exactly mid-way in my PhD in computer science. Is this the right time to start looking for a post doc?

Comment: I deleted the second part of your question, because it did not seem to have a direct connection with the main part of your question. If they are connected perhaps edit to make the link clearer or ask separate question about the funding aspect.

Answer (score 1):

Around your last year.

So much of this comes from networking though, so it is important to be meeting people at conferences long before you are about to graduate.

In the US, many postdoc positions are filled quite late (often after faculty offers have gone out, so mid to late Spring, maybe even early Summer) but you should start talking to potential postdoc advisors maybe a year before your graduation to put a bug in their ear.